# use 'genemu_jqueryimage' in form

Tags: php, symfony

When I install `GenemuFormBundle` in `Symfony2.3` and write in form `->add('image','genemu_jqueryimage')`

Then show me error :-

```
 genemu/form-bundle/Genemu/Bundle/FormBundle/Form/JQuery/Type/FileType.php line 57
```

May be this version compatibility problem.
So,I created issue on: https://github.com/genemu/GenemuFormBundle/issues/321

Any one know this this ?
I want this Bundle functionality because this is provide image crop option.

FileType.php:-

```
<?php

namespace Genemu\Bundle\FormBundle\Form\JQuery\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\Options;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

use Genemu\Bundle\FormBundle\Form\Core\EventListener\FileListener;
use Genemu\Bundle\FormBundle\Form\JQuery\DataTransformer\FileToValueTransformer;

/**
 * FileType
 */
class FileType extends AbstractType
{
private $options;
private $rootDir;

/**
 * Constructs
 *
 * @param array  $options
 * @param string $rootDir
 */
public function __construct(array $options, $rootDir)
{
    $this->options = $options;
    $this->rootDir = $rootDir;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $configs = $options['configs'];

    $builder
        ->addEventSubscriber(new FileListener($this->rootDir, $options['multiple']))
        ->addViewTransformer(new FileToValueTransformer($this->rootDir, $configs['folder'], $options['multiple']))
        ->setAttribute('rootDir', $this->rootDir)
    ;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
{
    $view->vars = array_replace($view->vars, array(
        'type' => 'hidden',
        'value' => $form->getViewData(),
        'multiple' => $options['multiple'],
        'configs' => $options['configs'],
    ));
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $configs = $this->options;

    $resolver
        ->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => null,
            'required' => false,
            'multiple' => false,
            'configs' => array(),
        ))
        ->setNormalizers(array(
            'configs' => function (Options $options, $value) use ($configs) {
                if (!$options['multiple']) {
                    $value['multi'] = false;
                }

                return array_merge($configs, $value);
            }
        ))
    ;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getParent()
{
    return 'file';
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'genemu_jqueryfile';
}
}
```

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same thing (they say that there are two possibilities with genemu for upload / crop images) but with no success.

I ended up by using [ComurImageBundle](https://github.com/comur/ComurImageBundle). It lets you do what you want (upload with jquery file upload and crop with jcrop) and work exactly like genemu (adds a new formtype that you can use in front / admin...).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define field types in config.yml. Make sure you want to use fileds are defined...

```
Like;

genemu_form:
     tinymce:
       enabled: true
       theme:   modern 

     file:
        enabled:    true
        folder:     'uploads'

     select2:
         enabled: true
         configs:
              placeholder: Select a value
              width: on
              allowClear: true
              minimumInputLength: 0
      ....
```